# Spacing in a new list

Tags: tocloft

I am trying to make a nice table of contents (toc) for a `{book}`.
My book has a list of tables and a new list which appear in the toc.

When the item number in the lists is more than one digit, the spacing needs adjusting to prevent the item section numbering from running into the item name.

I use `\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}` / `\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{3em}` in the preamble, to change the spacing for the list of sections / tables, which works great.

[image: without/with adjustments]

But i still need to adjust the spacing for the new list

*I have tried*

`\setlength{\cftscinumwidth}{3em}`  to adjust the spacing in the new list but `\cftscinumwidth` isn't defined so clearly this won't work .

*How can I control the spacing in the new list?*

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em} % sets space in section numbering
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{3em} % sets space in table numbering 
% \setlength{\cftscinumwidth}{3em} % ERROR % sets space in scientists numbering 

\newlistof{scientists}{sci} {\listscientisttitle} 
\newcommand \listscientisttitle {List of Scientists}
\newcommand \scientistlist [1]  {%
  \refstepcounter{scientists}
  \addcontentsline{sci}{scientists}
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thescientists} #1}%
}
\newcommand \scientist [1] {\scientistlist{#1}{\underline{Scientist}: #1}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}

\listofscientists
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listscientisttitle}

\mainmatter
\chapter{some chapter}
\setcounter{section}{332}
\section{some section}
\paragraph{some paragraph}~\\
\setcounter{table}{332}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{some table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline 9 & 44 & 55 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}   
\end{table}                     
\setcounter{scientists}{332}
\scientist{Mr Black (200--280)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure weather to rollback the question and edit it, edit the answer, or to delete the post (too localised).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    \documentclass{book}
%   Packages        %
    \usepackage{float}                  %  Tables
    \usepackage{tocloft}                    %  Table of Contents
        \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}            %%  sets space in section numbering
        \setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{3em}            %%  sets space in table numbering
%   New Commands
\newlistof{scientists}{sci} {\listscientisttitle}
\newcommand \listscientisttitle     {List of Scientists}
\newcommand \scientistlist  [1] {\refstepcounter{scientists}
                            \addcontentsline{sci}{scientists}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thescientists}#1}}
\newcommand \scientist      [1] {\scientistlist{#1}{\underline{Scientist}: #1}}
  \setlength{\cftscientistsnumwidth}{3em}    % Length must be defined before it can be set - it isn't defined until you've created the new list
  \setlength{\cftscientistsindent}{\cfttabindent}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter{}      %%              FRONT MATTER                %%
    \tableofcontents{}
        \listoftables{}     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
        \listofscientists{} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listscientisttitle}

\mainmatter{}       %%              MAIN MATTER                 %%
\chapter{some chapter}
\setcounter{section}{332}   \section{some section}
%                         \paragraph{some paragraph}~\\
\setcounter{table}{332} \begin{table}[H]\centering  \caption{some table}
                        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                            \hline      9   &   44  &   55      \\
                            \hline
                        \end{tabular}
                    \end{table}
\setcounter{scientists}{332}
\scientist{Mr Black (200--280)}
\end{document}
```

[image: Space for Black]